# How to update two tables at the same time?

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to update `staff table` using `user table`  data all the same time! but i keep in getting different errors, it there a way i could do this! pleasee...

**here is the function**

```
public function editprofile(Request $data){
    $this->validate($data, [
        'name'=> 'required|string',
        'email'=> 'required|string',
        'education'=> 'required|string',
        'location'=> 'required|string',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $user_staff_code = $user->staff_code;
    $success =  DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $user_id)
        ->limit(1)
        ->update(array(
            'name' => $data->name,
            'email' => $data->email,
            'education' => $data->education,
            'location' => $data->location,
        ));
   if ($success){
       $staff = Staff::find($user_staff_code);
       $staff->name = $data->name;
       $staff->email = $data->email;
       $staff->education = $data->education;
       $staff->location = $data->location;
       $staff->save();
        Alert::success('Success', 'Staff profile updated');
         return redirect()->back();
   }else{
       Alert::error('Error', 'Staff profile failed to update');
       return redirect()->back();
   }
```

Comment: that code can only update `user table`, after running it the `staffs table `remains the same.

Comment: and you got `Staff profile failed to update` ?

Comment: why do you `limit` while fetching the `user` (where condition could be enough if id is unique) ? If your update statement doesn't make any changes on the `user` then the success will return `0`/`false`. It could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

When updating more than one table at a time, it is best to use [Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions). This will ensure all tables are updated without error, or any partial changes will be reverted. This is extremely important for maintaining your database integrity.

*Note: Your tables must be using a storage engine that supports transactions, such as InnoDB.*

This also gives you an opportunity to provide a meaningful error message that may give you insight into the problems you are experiencing. And on a side note, using consistent update methods will help to keep your code readable and easy to understand.

```php
public function editprofile(Request $data)
{
    $this->validate($data, [
        'name'=> 'required|string',
        'email'=> 'required|string',
        'education'=> 'required|string',
        'location'=> 'required|string',
    ]);

    // start the transaction
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        $user = Auth::user();

        // user is already a model and can be updated directly
        $user->update([
            'name' => $data->name,
            'email' => $data->email,
            'education' => $data->education,
            'location' => $data->location,
        ]);

        // determine if any changes were made to the user model
        // if yes, retrieve and update the staff model
        if (! empty($user->getChanges())) {
            $staff = Staff::find($user->staff_code);
            $staff->update([
                'name' => $data->name,
                'email' => $data->email,
                'education' => $data->education,
                'location' => $data->location,
            ]);
        }

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {

        // report the error to the logger
        report($exception);

        // roll back any partial changes
        DB::rollBack();

        // fail with a meaningful error
        Alert::error('Error', $exception->getMessage());
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // commit (end) transaction
    DB::commit();

    // success
    Alert::success('Success', 'Both profiles updated!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

In a production app, you may also want to add additional checks to ensure the models actually exist prior to attempting any updates.  For example:

```php
if ($staff) {
    $staff->update(...);
}
```

Also, if there is a relationship between user and staff, you may be able to reference it instead of looking up the model directly.

```php
// previous
$staff = Staff::find($user->staff_code);

// new
$staff = $user->staff;
```